# Magento 2 Commerce Edition: how to manage promo date ranges?

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart-price-rules

We are on M2.3 Commerce Edition. I have some cart price rules that were working fine and then suddenly quit working. They remain active and all conditions are met. The only thing I can think of is that there is a date range that has expired. But we cannot see any date range in the admin panel, so we cannot confirm this. I've read through several message boards and the user guides but it is unclear what to do.

I would appreciate any help. This issue is there for catalog price rules too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be some concern on the scheduled changes section.

Magento 2 provides two types of Promotions.

**1. Catalog Level** - applying on the product listing and product view page. No coupon code required.

**2. Shopping cart Rules** - As name suggests its applying on the shopping cart rules. Coupon may be required.

**For Catalog Price Rules** - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

**For Cart Price Rules** - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html

To Manage the schedule have a look at this **Scheduled Changes for Cart Price Rules**

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-cart-scheduled-changes.html

Try to have a deep read on the following points.

> If a campaign that includes a price rule is initially created without
>   an end date, the campaign cannot later be edited to include an end
>   date. It is recommended that you either add an end date when you
>   create the campaign, or create a duplicate version of the existing
>   campaign and add the end date to the duplicate as needed.

=> **Content Staging**
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/cms/content-staging.html